# how do i update listview item index inside thread

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe7

i am creating project that allow multi users to login and add there details inside `listview` but i am stuck with problem , but First here is my threading code with comment implementation

```
type
  TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD = class(TThread)
  private
    FListView: TListView;
    FListViewIdx: Integer;
    FMs: TMemoryStream;
    FURL: String;
    procedure UpdateVisual; // update after download
    function DownloadToStream: Boolean; // download function
    function CheckURL(const URL: Widestring): Boolean;
    // Check if its http url using urlmon
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property URL: String read FURL write FURL;
    property ListView: TListView read FListView write FListView;
    property ListViewIdx: Integer read FListViewIdx write FListViewIdx;
  end;

function TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD.CheckURL(const URL: Widestring): Boolean;
begin
  if IsValidURL(nil, PWideChar(URL), 0) = S_OK then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD.DownloadToStream: Boolean;
var
  aIdHttp: TIdHttp;
begin
  Result := False;
  if CheckURL(URL) = False then
    exit;
  aIdHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    aIdHttp.Request.UserAgent :=
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    aIdHttp.Get(FURL, FMs);
    Result := FMs.Size > 0;
  finally
    aIdHttp.Free;
  end;
end;

// procedure to start adding items then download image then update image to current item index
Procedure TForm1.Add_Item(strCaption: String; ListView: TListView;
  strFile: String; strUniqueID: String);
begin
  With ListView.Items.Add do
  begin
    Caption := '';
    SubItems.Add(strCaption); // subitem 0
    SubItems.AddObject('IMA', TObject(aGif)); // subitem 1
    SubItems.Add(strUniqueID); // subitem 2 // Client id
    SubItems.Add('-'); // subitem 3 // Next User Idx (beside)
    With TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD.Create(False) do
    begin
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
      URL := strFile;
      ListView := ListView1;
      ListViewIdx := ListView1.Items.Count - 1;
      // this for define index of item that just added
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strname, image, strUniqueID: String;
begin
  Strname := 'Matrin';
  Add_Item(Strname, ListView1, image, strUniqueID);
end;

// Execute thread
procedure TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD.Execute;
begin
  FMs := TMemoryStream.Create;
  if DownloadToStream then
  // if download done then start update the visual inside list view
    synchronize(UpdateVisual);
end;

procedure TUPDATEAFTERDOWNLOAD.UpdateVisual;
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  i: Integer;
begin

  FMs.Position := 0;

  begin
    aGif := TGifImage.Create;
    aGif.LoadFromStream(FMs);
    aGif.Transparent := True;
    FListView.Items[FListViewIdx].SubItems.Objects[1] := TObject(aGif);
    if Streamin = True then
    begin
      for i := 0 to ListView.Items.Count - 1 do
        if ListView.Items[i].SubItems[3] = IntToStr(IDCLIENT) then
        begin
          ExchangeItems(ListView, FListViewIdx, 0);
        end;
    end;
  end;
  FMs.Free;

end;
```

Every thing working fine only i got problem when i try to `ExchangeItems(ListView, FListViewIdx, 0);` text exchanged but always image stay at wrong index if there 5 or 10 clients , i think the way that i do it is missed up

Forget to add Exchange items function

```
procedure ExchangeItems(lv: TListView; i, j: Integer);
var
  tempLI: TListItem;
begin
  lv.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    tempLI := TListItem.Create(lv.Items);
    tempLI.Assign(lv.Items.Item[i]);
    lv.Items.Item[i].Assign(lv.Items.Item[j]);
    lv.Items.Item[j].Assign(tempLI);
    tempLI.Free;
  finally
    lv.Items.EndUpdate
  end;
end;
```

**Updated information**

i tried to move GIF images to the TListItem.Data property but image shows empty now

```
procedure TFORM1.UpdateVisual(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage);
var
 Item: TListItem;
i : integer;
begin
 Item := TListItem(AUserData);

  if ListView1.Items.IndexOf(Item) = -1 then
    Exit;

  Item.Data:= AImage;// iam not sure if this right or wrong
  AImage := nil;

if recorder.Active = True then
      begin
       for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1
     do if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = IntToStr(UniqueID)
     then
     begin
     ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);
     ListView1.Invalidate;
     SendCommandWithParams(TCPClient, 'Streamin', IntToStr(UniqueID) + Sep);
     end;
   end;
end;
```

**that's how i use `gif` inside `listview` `OnDrawitem` event**

```
procedure TFORM1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
Var
  xOff, yOff : Integer;
  R: TRect;
  i : Integer;
  NewRect : TRect;
begin
    // Client image
      NewRect := Rect;
      NewRect.Right  := Sender.Column[0].Width - 4; // for Right Justify
      NewRect.Left   := NewRect.Right  - ImageList1.Width;
      NewRect.Top    := NewRect.Top + 2;
      NewRect.Bottom := NewRect.Bottom;
      Sender.Canvas.StretchDraw( NewRect, TGIFImage( Item.data) );
end;
```

also for `gif` animation  i am using timer for repaint `listview`

```
procedure TFrom1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
{$j+}
  Const iCount : Cardinal = 0;
{$j-}
begin
  inc(iCount);
  if (iCount * TTimer(Sender).Interval) > 500 then
  begin
    iCount := 0;
  end;
  ListView1.Invalidate; // This is for animation over ListView Canvas
end;
```

and this when i send stream to other clients thats what should happend

```
procedure TFORM1.Streamin;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1
    do if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = Trim(CLIENTID) then
  begin
  R:= listview1.Items[i].Index;
   ExchangeItems( ListView1, R, 0);
  end;
   Panel2.Top  := xSelItemTop;
   panel2.Visible := true;
   panelmeter.Visible := True;
end;
```

i posted every thing in my project i follow remy  advice and answer this issues seems very complicated i cannot catch any false in coding hope some one knows whats up

**Updates**

by using `wininet` problem reduced but when execute requested  too fast problem happened is it from the timer ?

**Update**

after create stand alone application the only problem is in exchange items it has some times false index by change exchange item by following code

```
procedure ExchangeItems(lv: TListView; ItemFrom, ItemTo: Word);
var
 Source, Target: TListItem;
begin
  lv.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
 Source := lv.Items[ItemFrom];
 Target := lv.Items.Insert(ItemTo);
 Target.Assign(Source);
 Source.Free;
  finally
    lv.Items.EndUpdate
  end;
end;
```

it work good but some times its insert empty item and application abort until re exchange happened

**updated mcve**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, JPEG, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, GIFImg, GraphUtil,
  Vcl.ImgList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Additem: TButton;
    Exchange: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    AddToSTringlistFirst: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AdditemClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ExchangeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddToSTringlistFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
     namelist: TList;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Add_Item(strCaption: String; ListView: TListView; strFile: String;
    boolBlink: Boolean; strUniqueID, Currentstatus: string);
    procedure UpdateVisual(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer;
      var AImage: TGifImage);
  end;

    type
  TDownloadUpdateVisualEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage) of object;

  type
  TURLDownload = class(TThread)
  private
    FGif         : TGifImage;
    FOnUpdateVisual: TDownloadUpdateVisualEvent;
    FUserData: Pointer;
    FURL         : String;
    procedure DoUpdateVisual;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
  constructor Create(const AUrl: String; AOnUpdateVisual: TDownloadUpdateVisualEvent; AUserData: Pointer); reintroduce;
  end;


  Tcollectlist = class(TObject)
  Name: String;
  icon:string;
  UniqueID : Dword;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  xProcessingTime : Boolean = False;
  aGIF : TGifImage;
  jpg : TJPEGImage;
  png : TPngImage;
  Status : string = '-';
  xSelItemLeft   : Integer = 0;
  xSelItemTop    : Integer = 0;
  recorder : Boolean;
  UniqueID : Dword;
  xboolBlink : Boolean = False;
  listMS: TMemoryStream;


implementation

uses wininet;

{$R *.dfm}

{$j+}
  Const boolblink : boolean = false;
  Const Sep = '#$%^&';
{$j-}



constructor TURLDownload.Create(const AUrl: String; AOnUpdateVisual: TDownloadUpdateVisualEvent; AUserData: Pointer);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FUrl := AUrl;
  FOnUpdateVisual:= AOnUpdateVisual;
  FUserData := AUserData;
end;


procedure ExchangeItems(lv: TListView; ItemFrom, ItemTo: Word);
var
 Source, Target: TListItem;
begin
  lv.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
 Source := lv.Items[ItemFrom];
    Target := lv.Items.Insert(ItemTo);
    Target.Assign(Source);
    Source.Free;
  finally
    lv.Items.EndUpdate
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
namelist := TList.Create;
  // This is for repaint the ListView and so for the animation
    Timer1.Interval       := 10;
    Timer1.Enabled        := true;

  // This is for enlarge the ListView height
  //   ImageList1.Width      := 50;
  //   ImageList1.Height     := 30;
  With ListView1 do
  begin
    SmallImages    := ImageList1;
    ViewStyle      := vsReport;
    RowSelect      := True;
    ReadOnly       := True;
    OwnerDraw      := True;
    DoubleBuffered := True;
    With Columns.Add do Width := (ImageList1.Width+4)*2; // Caption
    With Columns.Add do Width := ListView1.Width - ListView1.Columns[0].Width;  // 0 Name
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
Var
  xOff, yOff : Integer;
  i : Integer;
    R: TRect;
  NewRect : TRect;
begin
  With TListView(Sender).Canvas do
  begin
    if Item.Selected then
    begin
          SetRect(R, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom-( (Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top) div 2 ) );
      SetRect(R, Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom-( (Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top) div 2 ), Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom );
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
      Sender.Canvas.Pen.Width   := 0;

      //Sender.Canvas.Font.Color  := clBlue;
      //Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
      //Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      Rectangle( Rect.Left, Rect.Top,  Rect.Right, Rect.Top + ImageList1.Height);
    end;
    xSelItemTop    := sender.Top + ImageList1.Height;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    // User State Image
     if (Item.SubItems[5] <> '-') then
     begin
      if Panel2.Visible AND (Item.Index = 0) then
     else
     ImageList1.Draw( Sender.Canvas, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, StrToInt(Item.SubItems[5]) );
      end;
    // User Image
      NewRect := Rect;
      NewRect.Right  := Sender.Column[0].Width - 4; // for Right Justify
      NewRect.Left   := NewRect.Right  - ImageList1.Width;
      NewRect.Top    := NewRect.Top + 2;
      NewRect.Bottom := NewRect.Bottom;
      Sender.Canvas.StretchDraw( NewRect, TGIFImage( Item.data) );

    // Image - Beside User
      if Item.SubItems[4] <> '-' then
      begin
        NewRect := Rect;
        NewRect.Left   := NewRect.Left  + ImageList1.Width; // after StateImage offset
        NewRect.Right  := NewRect.Left  + ImageList1.Width;
        NewRect.Top    := NewRect.Top    + 4;
        NewRect.Bottom := NewRect.Bottom - 4;
        Sender.Canvas.StretchDraw( NewRect, TGIFImage( TListView(Sender).Items[StrToInt(Item.SubItems[4])].SubItems.Objects[1]) );
      end;

    // --- Caption and Text --- //
    xOff := Rect.Left;
    for i := 1 to TListView(sender).Columns.Count-1 do // 1,2,3,4,5,6
    begin
      xOff := xOff + TListView(Sender).Columns[i-1].Width;
      yOff := Rect.Top + ((ImageList1.Height-Canvas.TextHeight('H')) div 2);
      if xboolBlink or ( Item.SubItems[2] = '' )
        then sender.canvas.font.color := clgray
        else sender.canvas.font.color := clred;
      TextOut( xOff, yOff, Item.SubItems[i-1] );
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
{$j+}
  Const iCount : Cardinal = 0;
{$j-}
begin
  inc(iCount);
  if (iCount * TTimer(Sender).Interval) > 500 then
  begin  // this is for blink text which subitem[2] contains 'blink'
    xboolBlink := NOT xboolBlink;
    iCount := 0;
  end;
  ListView1.Invalidate; // This is for animation over ListView Canvas
end;


procedure parselist(Line: string; var strName, strUniqueID,icon: string);
var
  P, I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  repeat
    P := Pos(Sep, Line);
    if P <> 0 then
    begin
      Inc(I);
      case I of
        1: strName     := Copy(Line, 1, P - 1);
        2: strUniqueID := Copy(Line, 1, P - 1);
        3: icon  := Copy(Line, 1, P - 1);
      end;
      Delete(Line, 1, P + Length(Sep) - 1);
    end;
  until (I = 3) or (P = 0) or (Line = '')
end;


procedure TForm1.AdditemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
I : integer;
Line: string;
strName, strUniqueID, icon : String;
strSelectedUID : String;
Sl : Tstringlist;
begin
  if ListView1.Selected <> nil
      then strSelectedUID := Listview1.Selected.SubItems[3]
      else strSelectedUID := '';
    listview1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
finally
    listview1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
    if Assigned(listms) then
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    begin
      try
        listms.Position := 0;
        Sl.LoadFromStream(listms);
        for I := 0 to SL.Count -1  do
        begin
            Line := SL.Strings[I];
            parselist(Line, strName, strUniqueID, icon);
            boolblink := True;
           Add_Item( strName, ListView1, icon, boolblink, strUniqueID, Status);
        end;
      finally
       Sl.Free
      end;
      listms.Free;

    if strSelectedUID <> '' then
      begin
        for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1
          do if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = strSelectedUID
            then Listview1.Items[i].Selected := True;
      end;
    end;
end;


procedure TForm1.AddToSTringlistFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  image : string;
  collectlist : Tcollectlist;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Sl : Tstringlist;
begin
collectlist := Tcollectlist.Create;
SL := TStringList.Create;
image := edit1.Text;
collectlist.Name := 'Martinloanel';
collectlist.UniqueID :=  StrToint('5555' + intTostr(1));
collectlist.icon := image;
namelist.Add(collectlist);

 try
    // Collect List
    for I := 0 to namelist.Count - 1 do
    begin
      collectlist := Tcollectlist(namelist.Items[I]);
      SL.Add(collectlist.Name + Sep + IntToStr(collectlist.UniqueID) + Sep +  collectlist.icon + Sep);
    end;
// Send List
    for I := 0 to namelist.Count - 1 do
    begin
      collectlist := Tcollectlist(namelist.Items[I]);
      if (SL.Count > 0) then
      begin
        MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
        listms :=  TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          SL.SaveToStream(MS);
          MS.Position := 0;
          listms.LoadFromStream(MS);

        finally
         MS.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Sl.Free
  end;
end;

Procedure TForm1.Add_Item( strCaption: String; ListView : TListView; strFile: String; boolBlink : Boolean; strUniqueID:String; Currentstatus: string);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
Currentstatus := Status;
  begin
    Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption   := '';
    Item.SubItems.Add( strCaption ); // subitem 0
    Item.SubItems.AddObject( 'IMA', nil); // subitem 1
    if boolBlink
      then  Item.SubItems.Add( 'blink' ) // subitem 2
      else  Item.SubItems.Add( '' );     // subitem 2
      Item.SubItems.Add( strUniqueID );                  // subitem 3 // UniqueID
      UniqueID := strToint(strUniqueID);
    Item.SubItems.Add('-');                            // subitem 4 // Next User Idx (beside)
    Item.SubItems.Add(Currentstatus);                              // subitem 5 // StateIdx
    TURLDownload.Create(strFile, UpdateVisual, Item);
    end;
  end;



  procedure TForm1.ExchangeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
recorder := True;
end;

procedure TURLDownload.DoUpdateVisual;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnUpdateVisual) then
    FOnUpdateVisual(Self, FUserData, FGif);
end;

procedure TURLDownload.Execute;
var
  aMs: TMemoryStream;
  hSession     : HINTERNET;
  hService     : HINTERNET;
  lpBuffer     : array[0..1023] of Byte;
  dwBytesRead  : DWORD;
  dwBytesAvail : DWORD;
  dwTimeOut    : DWORD;
begin
  FGif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
  aMs := TMemoryStream.Create;
  hSession := InternetOpen('anyname', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(hSession) then Exit;
    try
      hService := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, PChar(FUrl), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    if hService = nil then
      Exit;
      try
      dwTimeOut := 60000;
      InternetSetOption(hService, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, @dwTimeOut, SizeOf(dwTimeOut));
      if InternetQueryDataAvailable(hService, dwBytesAvail, 0, 0) then
      repeat
      if not InternetReadFile(hService, @lpBuffer[0], SizeOf(lpBuffer), dwBytesRead) then
      Break;
      if dwBytesRead <> 0 then
      aMs.WriteBuffer(lpBuffer[0], dwBytesRead);
      until dwBytesRead = 0;
      finally
       InternetCloseHandle(hService);
      end;
      aMs.Position := 0;
      FGif.LoadFromStream(aMs);
      FGif.Transparent := True;
    finally
      aMs.Free;
      InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    end;
    if Assigned(FOnUpdateVisual) then
    begin
      Synchronize(DoUpdateVisual);
    end;
  finally
    FGif.Free;
  end;
end;




  procedure TForm1.UpdateVisual(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage);
var
 Item: TListItem;
i : integer;
begin
 Item := TListItem(AUserData);

  if ListView1.Items.IndexOf(Item) = -1 then
    Exit;

  Item.Data := AImage;
  AImage := nil;

if recorder = True then
      begin
       for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1
     do if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = IntToStr(UniqueID)
     then
     begin
     ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);
     ListView1.Invalidate;
     end;
   end;
end;


end.
```

Comment: The answer is you don't. You can't do UI updates within any thread other than the main thread. You will have to synchronize events of some kind to inform the main thread that it needs to perform the update.

Comment: @JerryDodge The `UpdateVisual` is called synchronized

Comment: @SirRufo Yeah I just caught that. Still not a very good design to feed controls into a thread - the thread should be self-contained without knowledge of the UI. I'd be worried if the contents of the list changed before this update is done - where the Index has changed between the time the thread started and completed.

Comment: @JerryDodge Indeed this implementation is very odd and should never reach production code ;o)

Comment: i think i am totally missed up can i reach the same approach in better way ?

Comment: Take a look a virtual string tree. You can add all of your elements to an internal list and then just have the tree display the visual contents of the list.

Comment: You say you are having problems with `ExchangeItems()`, but you did not show what it is actually doing.

Comment: EXchangeitems should move item index while client streamin bring the item to top

Comment: So again, WHAT IS THE ACTUAL PROBLEM? There is nothing wrong with your `ExchangeItems()` implementation.  It exchanges the `TListItem` data correctly, including `SubItems` and their associated objects.  So if your stored images are not appearing correctly, you must not be managing them correctly, but you have not shown that code, either.  `TListView` itself does not use the `TListItem.SubItems.Objects[]` property for anything, so you have to be using it somewhere in your own code.  Please show that code as well.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason why you are storing your GIF images in the `TListItem.SubItems.Objects[]` property and not in the `TListItem.Data` property instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i put the updated code following your instruction still behave same as old code but your code some times move the actual image to another item index so if there 5 or 10 clients there image we look like its replaced and they collected on one item place and this problem caused when item exchanged only if iam not doing item exchange image beside item load correctly

Comment: iam really confused its seems every thing is done in right way but i dont know why that issue caused

Comment: I strongly advise you to move your GIF images to the `TListItem.Data` property.  `TListView` does not use the `TListItem.SubItems.Objects` property for anything useful. You are relying on the fact that `TSubItems` derives from `TStringList`, but that is an implementation detail. Just because `TStringList` happens to hold object pointers is not a guarantee that `TListView` will not lose them. The `Data` property, on the other hand, belongs to `TListItem` itself and `TListView` actively manages and preserves `Data` values when manipulating list items.

Comment: If you are still having the same problem after moving the GIF images to `TListItem.Data`, then please stop posting tidbits and provide an actual [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: can you tell me how to move my GIF image To `Tlistitem.data` i don't catch what you mean

Comment: @RemyLebeau i update the question with try to move Gif image to `TListItem.Data` i dont know if its right or wrong iam new with this

Comment: You are assigning the `TListItem.Data` fine, but you STILL have not shown the code that is USING the GIF image after it has been downloaded. WHERE and HOW are you displaying the image? You keep saying the images do not display correctly, but you have not shown HOW you are displaying them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i added updated code by following your advise , when item exchange it succeed to exchange item name but image have the same issues when download process take long the item that exchanged get image of other client and other client image disappeared

Comment: You need to call `ListView1.Invalidate()` after exchanging the items, and your timer should be calling `Invalidate()` instead of `Repaint()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau change repaint to invalidate request invalidate after exchange item updated code also i added image to see the result every time i exchange item that's happened still same result

Comment: @RemyLebeau by using `wininet` as you suggested me in the other question problem reduced but if i requested execute thread fast problem happened image replaced is ther from timer of listview ?

Comment: @MartinLoanel: How you *download* images has no effect on how you *display* them. You have a *display* problem, but I can't find anything in the code I have given you that would cause a *display* problem. When a new `TListItem` is created, the download thread assigns the image to THAT `TListItem`, and no matter where that `TListItem` is relocated within the `TListView`, its image should be following it. And since you are using the `OnDrawItem` event, it should be drawing whatever image is currently assigned to the `TListItem` being drawn. There is no possibility for drawing the wrong image...

Comment: @MartinLoanel: ... unless you are messing around with your `TListItem` objects in code you have not shown, and losing the image assignments along the way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau now i posted every thing about my code from sending command to client to `GETLIST` to adding items and creating the thread to download .

Comment: every time i enter channel this `GETLIST` command requested to update listview with current client on this channel and check if he streaming or not and remark who is streaming by exchange his name to top of listview

Comment: Now you are confusing the matter with irrelevant details.  At this point, you need to stop what you are doing and create a new test project with **absolute minimal** code (create some list items, download images for them, display the images, and exchange the items - *nothing else!*). If you get *minimal* code working, you can figure out what your main app is doing wrong and fix it. If you cannot get *minimal* code working, you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau forget to mention if no one streaming that's means exchange items not requested , so if no one streaming no problem happened at all names  added correctly with there image , only problem caused when exchange item requested

Comment: i will create stand alone app and i will post its details here

Comment: @RemyLebeau i created stand alone application adding several items the  problem in exchange item from the beginning some times it moves empty index question updated with new code  but some times exchange items add empty item to top then application abort until exchange correct items again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89340/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-martinloanel).

Comment: @RemyLebeau MCVE Added to test click  many times on `AddToSTringlistFirst` button then click on `Additem` button then click on exchange button then try `AddStringFirst` then add item again see whats happend

Comment: any idea after adding MCVE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TDownloadImageReadyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage) of object;

  TDownloadImage = class(TThread)
  private
    FURL: String;
    FGif: TGifImage;
    FOnImageReady: TDownloadImageReadyEvent;
    FUserData: Pointer;
    procedure DoImageReady;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AUrl: String; AOnImageReady: TDownloadImageReadyEvent; AUserData: Pointer); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TDownloadImage.Create(const AUrl: String; AOnImageReady: TDownloadImageReadyEvent; AUserData: Pointer);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FUrl := AUrl;
  FOnImageReady := AOnImageReady;
  FUserData := AUserData;
end;

procedure TDownloadImage.Execute;
var
  aMs: TMemoryStream;
  aIdHttp: TIdHttp;
begin
  FGif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
    aMs := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      aIdHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
      try
        aIdHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
        aIdHttp.Get(FURL, aMs);
      finally
        aIdHttp.Free;
      end;
      aMs.Position := 0;
      FGif.LoadFromStream(aMs);
      FGif.Transparent := True;
    finally
      aMs.Free;
    end;
    if Assigned(FOnImageReady) then
      Synchronize(DoImageReady);
    end;
  finally
    FGif.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TDownloadImage.DoImageReady;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnImageReady) then
    FOnImageReady(Self, FUserData, FGif);
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Add_Item(const strCaption, strFile, strUniqueID: String);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := '';
  Item.SubItems.Add(strCaption); // subitem 0
  Item.SubItems.Add('IMA'); // subitem 1
  Item.SubItems.Add(strUniqueID); // subitem 2 // Client id
  Item.SubItems.Add('-'); // subitem 3 // Next User Idx (beside)
  Item.Data := nil;
  TDownloadImage.Create(strFile, ImageReady, Item);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  TGifImage(Item.Data).Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strname, image, strUniqueID: String;
begin
  Strname := 'Matrin';
  image := ...;
  strUniqueID := ...;
  Add_Item(Strname, image, strUniqueID);
end;

procedure TForm1.ImageReady(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage);
var
  Item: TListItem;
  i: Integer;
  sClientID: string;
begin
  Item := TListItem(AUserData);

  if ListView1.Items.IndexOf(Item) = -1 then
    Exit;

  Item.Data := AImage;
  AImage := nil;

  if Streamin then
  begin
    sClientID := IntToStr(IDCLIENT);
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if ListView.Items[i].SubItems[3] = sClientID then
      begin
        ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `FOnImageReady := AImageReady;` in create constructor  where AimageReady declared at  ?

Comment: `AImageReady` should have been `AOnImageReady`. I have corrected it.

Comment: i got the same results item text exchanged but image still in wrong index

Comment: it has the same effect items text exchanged correctly but images got wrong index

Comment: Then you are not exchanging the items correctly.  Please update your question to show the actual code for `ExchangeItems()`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `ExchangeItems()` implementation, so the problem has to be elsewhere in code you have not shown yet. How are you actually using the GIF images that are stored in the `TListItem.SubItems.Objects[]` property?

Comment: sorry for delay , i will  put my updated code i did every thing as your example shows

Comment: thank you @remy Lebeau for improve the code the problem was on exchange item from beginning not the procedure itself but its call  here `ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);` it shouldn't be `item.index` it should be  `ListView1.Items[I].index`

Comment: `ListView1.Items[I].index` and `I` are the same value, so just use `I` to avoid the overhead of retrieving and querying the `TListItem` at index `I`: `ExchangeItems(ListView1, I, 0);`