# Why does this procedure raise an exception?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe7

I am trying to handle a problem that I mention in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289114/how-do-i-update-listview-item-index-inside-thread), so I am trying to exchange items inside a `listview` using different procedure.

Here is the procedure that I am trying to use

```
procedure ExchangeItems(lv: TListView; Const ItemFrom, ItemTo: Integer);
var
    Source, Target: TListItem;
begin
    lv.Items.BeginUpdate;

    try
        Source := lv.Items[ItemFrom];
        Target := lv.Items.Insert(ItemTo);
        Target.Assign(Source);
        Source.Free;
    finally
        lv.Items.EndUpdate
    end;
end;
```

It is working really well, but sometimes after using my application and request this procedure several times with fast clicks, it exchanges an empty item that does not exist in my `listview` and raise this exception

> First chance exception at $75164B32. Exception class EConvertError
>   with message 'Cannot assign a nil to a TListItem'.

That's how I exchange items if some condition is met

```
procedure TFORM1.UpdateVisual(Sender: TObject; AUserData: Pointer; var AImage: TGifImage);
var
 Item: TListItem;
 i : integer;
begin
 Item := TListItem(AUserData);

  if ListView1.Items.IndexOf(Item) = -1 then
    Exit;

  Item.Data := AImage;
  AImage := nil;
// if recorder is active then select item that equal to ClientID and exchange it to Top
if recorder = True then
      begin
       for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1
     do if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3] = IntToStr(ClientID)
     then
     begin
     ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);
     ListView1.Invalidate;
     end;
   end;
end;
```

How can I handle this exception?

Comment: Can't you just make sure it's not nil before you assign the value?

Comment: do you mean check  `item.index`  is not nil ? how ever if you use your compiler and even `showmessage(results)` you will find const values are not nil .

Comment: If that's causing the error, yes. Or does delphi not show what exactly causes the error?

Comment: debugger shows the exception that i posted but does not shows any nil values there is MCVE in my other question if you want to test

Comment: You mean the question where you do UI work in a thread?

Comment: yes David i posted MCVE There

Comment: Are you still accessing the UI from a thread

Comment: I don't own any version of delphi. Thus I can't really test it.
But you say it only occurs when you click really fast. Could you for example make a small delay before it gets reexecuted? I. e. put the thread to sleep for a few milliseconds.

Comment: @szoszk That is terrible advice.  Covering up a bug doesn't make it go away - the only sensible solution is to identify the root cause and fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i synchronize `UpdateVisual` event first then if everu thing `assigned` procedure starts to do its job

Comment: @szoszk If my hands were infected and bleed and tried to wash the wound without making sure that the water is clean there is a possibility that my whole hand will be cut off

Comment: the  issues was in `ExchangeItems(ListView1, Item.Index, 0);`  item.index is selecting all items in `Tlistitem` it should be  `ListView1.Items[I].index` seems working good now