# how do i correctly draw gif image from resource inside listview?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe7

i have `listview` item that i try to add image to its `subitem` as `status-image` i already can set image from image list but i want to get ride of image list and use images from resource i already created resource file and try to add `Tgifimage` to item draw but now image image not drawing

here is my code

```
procedure TForm1.Add_Item(strCaption: String; ListView: TListView;
  strFile: String; boolBlink: Boolean; strUniqueID: String;
  CurrentStatus: string);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := '';
  Item.SubItems.Add(strCaption);// subitem 0
  Item.SubItems.AddObject( '0', nil ); // subitem 1
  Item.SubItems.Add( strUniqueID ); // subitem 2 // UniqueID
  Item.SubItems.Add('0'); // subitem 3 // Next User Idx (beside)
  Item.SubItems.Add(Currentstatus); // subitem 4 // StateIdx
  Item.Data := nil;
  SetItemStatusGif(Item, Currentstatus); // here start to set status
  end;

  // here setitemStatusGif procedure

  procedure TForm1.SetItemStatusGif(Item: TListItem; State: String);
  var
    ResStream: TResourceStream;
    aGif: TGifImage;
    strStateImg: String;
    ImgIdx: Integer;
  begin
    strStateImg := 'State_' + State;
    ImgIdx := StatusGifs.IndexOf(strStateImg);
    if ImgIdx <> -1 then
      aGif := TGifImage(StatusGifs.Objects[ImgIdx])
    else
    begin
      try
        ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, strStateImg, RT_RCDATA);
        try
          aGif := TGifImage.Create;
          try
            aGif.LoadFromStream(ResStream);
            aGif.Transparent := True;
            StatusGifs.AddObject(strStateImg, aGif);
          except
            aGif.Free;
            raise;
          end;
        finally
          ResStream.Free;
        end;
      except
        aGif := nil;
      end;
    end;
    Item.SubItems.Objects[1] := aGif;
    ListView1.UpdateItems(Item.Index, Item.Index);
  end;

  // here listview draw event code
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
    Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
Var
    xOff, yOff: Integer;
    R: TRect;
    i: Integer;
    NewRect: TRect;
begin
    With TListView(Sender).Canvas do
    begin // User State Image
    if (StrToint(Item.SubItems[1]) <> 0) And (Item.SubItems[1] <> '') then
    begin
    NewRect := Rect;
    NewRect.Left   := NewRect.Left + 2;
    NewRect.Width  := 24;
    Newrect.Height :=  23;
    NewRect.Top    := NewRect.Top;
    NewRect.Bottom := NewRect.Bottom;
    if Panel2.Visible AND (Item.Index = 0) then
    //do nothing
else
   Sender.Canvas.StretchDraw( NewRect, TGIFImage( Item.SubItems.Objects[1])  );
   end;
       end;
        end;


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListView1.Invalidate; // This is for animation over ListView Canvas
end;
```

Comment: You are drawing the object in SubItems.Objects[1] but I don't see anywhere that you are putting a reference to a TGIFImage (or any other object for that matter) in the SubItems.Objects[1] property.  The code that loads the GIF appears to create a TGIFImage, load a resource, set it Transparent and then Free it without making any use of it.  The code as posted simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: the code is completely mess i know that because i still don't know  how to reach the same approach correctly with `subitem 5` i tried `Item.SubItems.Addobject(Currentstatus, nil);` i`am much confused how to do it i`am still beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We covered this a month ago in your other question:

[how do i update listview item index inside thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289114)

In that question, you were downloading images from online, where the download thread creates the `TGifImage` object and assigns it to a `TListItem` for drawing.  Now, you want to add resource images.  You still have to create a `TGifImage` object for them, and assign that to your `TListItem` object so you can draw it.  You just don't need to use a thread to handle that.  When you add a new item to the list, you can create the `TGifImage` object immediately and fill it from the resource, eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure ListView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
    ...
  private
    StatusGifs: TStringList;
    procedure Add_Item(strCaption: String; ListView: TListView; strFile: String; boolBlink: Boolean; strUniqueID: String; CurrentStatus: string);
    procedure StatuseHandle;
    procedure SetItemStatusGif(Item: TListItem; State: String);
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  StatusGifs := TStringList.Create(True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  StatusGifs.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  TGifImage(Item.SubItems.Objects[1]).Free;
  TGifImage(Item.Data).Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Add_Item(strCaption: String; ListView: TListView; strFile: String; boolBlink: Boolean; strUniqueID: String; CurrentStatus: string);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := '';
  Item.SubItems.Add( strCaption ); // subitem 0
  Item.SubItems.AddObject( 'IMA', TGifImage.Create ); // subitem 1
  Item.SubItems.Add( strUniqueID ); // subitem 2 // UniqueID
  Item.SubItems.Add('0'); // subitem 3 // Next User Idx (beside)
  Item.SubItems.Add(Currentstatus); // subitem 4 // StateIdx
  Item.Data := nil; // populated by TURLDownload

  SetItemStatusGif(Item, Currentstatus);
  TURLDownload.Create(strFile, UpdateVisual, Item);
end;

procedure TForm1.StatuseHandle;
var
  i : integer;
  Item : TListItem;
begin
  try
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
    begin
      Item := ListView1.Items[i];
      if Item.SubItems[2] = Trim(LineToid) then
      begin
        Item.SubItems[4] := LineTostatus;
        SetItemStatusGif(Item, LineTostatus);
      end;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetItemStatusGif(Item: TListItem; State: String);
var
  ResStream  : TResourceStream;
  aGif : TGifImage;
  strStateImg : String;
  ImgIdx: Integer;
begin
  strStateImg := 'State_' + State;

  ImgIdx := StatusGifs.IndexOf(strStateImg);
  if ImgIdx <> -1 then
    aGif := TGifImage(StatusGifs.Objects[ImgIdx])
  else
  begin
    try
      ResStream  := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, strStateImg, RT_RCDATA);
      try
        aGif := TGifImage.Create;
        try
          aGif.LoadFromStream(ResStream);
          aGif.Transparent := True;
          StatusGifs.AddObject(strStateImg, aGif);
        except
          aGif.Free;
          raise;
        end;
      finally
        ResStream.Free;
      end;
    except
      aGif := nil;
    end;
  end;

  TGifImage(Item.SubItems.Objects[1]).Assign(aGif);
  ListView1.UpdateItems(Item.Index, Item.Index);
end;
```

Comment: i stuck with  problem when i add new item its get the latest Tgifimage pointer i make a question about it here

Comment: That implies that you are not managing your `TGifImage` pointers correctly.

Comment: `TGifImage` i thought when its create every `Tgifimage` have different pointer  i been trying to solve this issue 3 days ago with no progress , that image shows whats goung on http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9978/ct6jfnqmnj50s5tzg.jpg?size_id=4  current  Code added to the question

Comment: You modified the code I gave you. You changed the lines `Item.SubItems.AddObject( 'IMA', TGifImage.Create );` and `TGifImage(Item.SubItems.Objects[1]).Assign(aGif);` to `Item.SubItems.AddObject( '0', nil );` and `Item.SubItems.Objects[1] := aGif;`  You are making multiple list items with the same status value to point at the same `TGifImage` object in memory. Which is perfectly fine in this example, I should have thought of that when I wrote the `TStringList` caching code (just make sure to remove the corresponding `Free` in the `OnDeletion` event, if you have not already).

Comment: As for your flickering problem, given the code shown, I can only assume you are not managing your list item status values correctly. Where and how do you assign `LineTostatus` and call `StatusHandle`? Do you call `SetItemStatusGif` anywhere else other than the two places shown? And do you ever change the string value of `SubItems[1]`? You are not drawing the `TGifImage` when `SubItems[1]` is `''` or `'0'`.

Comment: yes i found the issue i been by false request `SetItemStatusGif` Twice , one when adding items and again when clear and adding items again solved when removed `SetItemStatusGif` From Add_item and request only from clear and add to listview thank you very much remy it works fine